Normal Vectors of Coupled Surfaces
I have two equations:
$$
f(x,y,z_1,z_2) = 0,\\
g(x,y,z_1,z_2) = 0
$$
for two functions of interest $z_1(x,y)$ and $z_2(x,y)$.
Something like:
$$
\sin(_1)+\log(_1+_2)=0,\\
(_1 _2)+\exp(_1+_2)=0,
$$
These functions are multivalued and I want to find where the "cusp" is where two branches meet. To find the cusp, I know I need find the z-component of the normal to the surface and let it equal zero i.e. However, I don't know how to take the gradient wrt $x,y,z$ when there are two different equation defining the surfaces.
How can I find expressions for the normal vector of a coupled system?

I think this question is more appropriate for MathSE instead of PSE. I suggest to move there it.

Unfortunately I asked there already but no answer sadly.

First of all, "the normal to the surface" is not a well-defined object. Your pair of equations describes a $2$-dimensional surface in $\mathbb R^4$, so at each regular point of the surface there will be a $2$-dimensional space of normal vectors.
What you're asking for is to identify the points on the surface where it cannot be expressed locally as a graph of $(z_1,z_2)$ as smooth functions of $(x,y)$. This is exactly what the implicit function theorem is made for: it tells you that the surface is locally such a graph at every point where the determinant of the following matrix is nonzero:
$$
M=
\left(
\begin{matrix}\displaystyle
\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_1} & 
\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_2}\\
\displaystyle\frac{\partial g}{\partial z_1} & 
\displaystyle\frac{\partial g}{\partial z_2}
\end{matrix}
\right).
$$
So the singularities ("cusps") you're looking for are contained in the set of points $(x,y,z_1,z_2)$ that are simultaneous solutions of the equations $f=0$, $g=0$, and $\det M=0$. In the case of the example you wrote down, I don't think you're going to be able to solve those equations explicitly; but in priniciple that's how to find the singularities.
It should be noted, however, that the implicit function theorem is not an "if and only if" statement -- there may be points where the three equations have a simultaneous solution, but the graph may still be perfectly nonsingular there. For a simple example, consider
$$f(x,y,z_1,z_2) = (z_1)^2, \qquad g(x,y,z_1,z_2) = z_2.
$$
The surface defined by $f=g=0$ is the $(x,y)$-plane, which is the graph
of the perfectly regular functions $z_1=0$ and $z_2=0$, with no singularities. However the matrix $M$ in this case has zero determinant everywhere on this graph, so the implicit function theorem is no help. There may be other tools you can bring to bear in a case like this, but I don't know of any systematic approach.
